# Assistance with re module script

Tags: python

I posted this question earlier [Approach for parsing file and creating dynamic data structure for use by another program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344547/approach-for-parsing-file-and-creating-dynamic-data-structure-for-use-by-another) and got some good suggestions.

So now I have something working and I want to see if there is a better way of doing it.

Background Information:

I basically need to parse a static properties file that I cannot modify at this time. Read some values from it and put it into a data structure that I can use in some scripts that I do have control of. The problem I'm facing is that I want to group "like" key/values together so I can access them in a loop later in my scripts. For example, my property file looks something like this actually.

```
somerandom.propname=value1
myhostname.APP_HOME=c:\\apps\\apphome
myhostname.DomainName=sampleDomain
myhostname.data.dir=D:\\data\\
sampleDomain.host=myhostname
sampleDomain.port=80
sampleDomain.sslport=443
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer1.port=8080
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer2.port=8012
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer1.sslport=8021
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer2.sslport=8022
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer1.name=MS1
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer2.name=MS2
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer1.host=myhostname
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer2.host=myHOST2
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer3.port=8031
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer4.port=8042
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer3.sslport=8043
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer4.sslport=8053
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer3.name=MS3
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer4.name=MS4
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer3.host=myhostHOST3
sampleDomain.ClusterManagedServer4.host=myhostHOST4
sampleDomain.AdminAccount=samplesuperadmin
sampleDomain.ServerName=myhostname222
sampleDomain.ServerPort=8008
sampleDomain.HeapSize=1234m

somerandom.propname=value2
anotherhostname.APP_HOME=c:\\apps\\apphome
anotherhostname.DomainName=sampleDomain
anotherhostname.data.dir=D:\\data\\
testDomain.host=anotherhostname
testDomain.port=80
testDomain.sslport=443
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer1.port=8080
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer2.port=8012
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer1.sslport=8021
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer2.sslport=8022
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer1.name=MS1
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer2.name=MS2
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer1.host=anotherhostname
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer2.host=anotherHOST2
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer3.port=8031
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer4.port=8042
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer3.sslport=8043
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer4.sslport=8053
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer3.name=MS3
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer4.name=MS4
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer3.host=anotherHOST3
testDomain.ClusterManagedServer4.host=anotherHOST4
testDomain.AdminAccount=superadminaccount
testDomain.ServerName=myservernamehere
testDomain.ServerPort=80
testDomain.HeapSize=1355m
```

So what I'm trying to do is match up all values of the "ClusterManagedServer#" where #=the number into some structure so I can loop thru it and for each host confgure the name, port, etc.

I have the following code working (just a proof of concept) and I have to use the existing modules that come with an earlier version of python so I can't download any modules and install them.

```
import re
from socket import gethostname

class Ddict(dict):
    def __init__(self, default=None):
        self.default = default

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not self.has_key(key):
            self[key] = self.default()
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)


propertyfile_name = 'SystemConfig.properties'

hname=gethostname()
print 'hostname is', hname

print '\ngetting domainname\n'
RE4 =(hname+'.DomainName=(\S+)(?:\s+|\Z)')

with open(propertyfile_name) as f:
    for (x) in re.findall(RE4,f.read()):
        dName=x
        print 'domain name is: ',dName

RE = (dName+'.ClusterManagedServer(\d+)\.host=(\S+)(?:\s+|\Z)')
RE1 =(dName+'.ClusterManagedServer(\d+)\.name=(\S+)(?:\s+|\Z)')
RE2 =(dName+'.ClusterManagedServer(\d+)\.sslport=(\d+)\s+' )
RE3 =(dName+'.ClusterManagedServer(\d+)\.port=(\d+)\s+' )

dico = Ddict( dict )

print '\n\nGetting values from property file:'


with open(propertyfile_name) as f:
    for (server,h) in re.findall(RE,f.read()):
        dico[server]['host']=h    

with open(propertyfile_name) as f:
    for (server,n) in re.findall(RE1,f.read()):
        dico[server]['name']=n    
        #print dico 

with open(propertyfile_name) as f:
    for (server,s) in re.findall(RE2,f.read()):
        dico[server]['sslport']=s    
        #print dico 

with open(propertyfile_name) as f:
    for (server,p) in re.findall(RE3,f.read()):
        dico[server]['port']=p   
        #print dico 

#print '\ndico is:'
#print dico

print '\n**for loop to print out values in dictionary **\n'
keys = dico.keys()
keys.sort()
for k in keys:
     print '\n'
     #print k
     #print dico[k]
     print dico[k]['name']
     print dico[k]['sslport']
     print dico[k]['host']
     print dico[k]['port']
     print '\n'
```

My question is, is there a better way to parse the file and get what I need instead of having to open the file 4 times to get the specific values?

Thanks

Comment: I was in the middle of editing it when someone else did it. Give me a break?

Comment: @user275633: You should be able to see the code before posting it.  Many, many, many folks fail to format the questions and don't seem to know that they've failed for format their questions.  Lacking ESP, I was unable to tell if you were unaware of the formatting or not.  Since my ESP failed utterly, I asked.

Comment: yes your correct you can and probably like many others do, I forgot to indent it when I was cut/pasting. Simple mistake that I realized after I posted it. Guess you need to tune up that ESP ;). Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @user275633: An explanation of things that may or may hot have happened. really very helpful.  Here's the point.  Delete the comments since they no longer apply to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(propertyfile_name) as f: 
    content= f.read()
    for (server,h) in re.findall(RE,content): 
        dico[server]['host']=h

    for (server,n) in re.findall(RE1,content):  
        dico[server]['name']=n

    for (server,s) in re.findall(RE2,content): 
        dico[server]['sslport']=s

    for (server,p) in re.findall(RE3,content): 
        dico[server]['port']=p
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a better option to streamline the regular expressions?

Comment: Rarely.  I'm not sure what improvements you imagine could be possible.  It's a properties file and you can easily parse the line without using **any** regular expressions, if that's what you're asking about.